Git Config credentials issue
I am using my friend's system to access my git repo, clone, and push new code.
But it shows:

https://github.com/MY_USERNAME/REPO denied access to MY_FRIENDS_USERNAME.

I updated the git credential helper but am still facing this issue. When I run the following command:
git config --global --get credential.helper

the output I get is store. I updated the following command to use cache:
git config --global credential.helper cache

but git is still picking up the Windows credentials and failing in authentication.
When I run the git push command, I want git to open browser to authenticate my username and return back to console and complete the push.
